# How to remove/add html tag in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to remove/add the html tag dynamically with condition in the javascript?

https://jsfiddle.net/kimsoon/Ldy9xhjt/3/

Example i need to remove the number 2 th column when button is clicked, insert back again when button is clicked. I have using this but does not work.

```
angular.element(document).find('.dataTable tfoot').remove($scope.items);///to remove
angular.element(document).find('.dataTable thead').prepend($scope.items);//to add
```

Comment: Your fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Angular documentation on `angular.element().find()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#!):

> Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag
>   name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead
>   `angular.element(document).find(...)` or `$document.find()`, or use the
>   standard DOM APIs, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll()`.

So, `angular.element(document).find(...)` can only be used lookup by *tag name* not *class name*.
Therefore, your code is not working because your `.find()` is not returning the element(s) you expect it to (in fact it's not returning any).

Use the DOM method `getElementsByClassName` to select using class name:

```js
const dataTable = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("dataTable"));
```

Then you can perform your prepends or removals on the wrapped angular `dataTable` element:

```js
dataTable.remove($scope.items); //to remove
dataTable.prepend($scope.items); //to add
```